# Get Data From Passport-azure-ad before DB config

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-active-directory, passport.js

```
var server;
var db;    

passport.use(new OIDCStrategy({
        identityMetadata: config.creds.identityMetadata,
        clientID: config.creds.clientID,
        responseType: config.creds.responseType,
        responseMode: config.creds.responseMode,
        redirectUrl: config.creds.redirectUrl,
        allowHttpForRedirectUrl: config.creds.allowHttpForRedirectUrl,
        clientSecret: config.creds.clientSecret,
        validateIssuer: config.creds.validateIssuer,
        isB2C: config.creds.isB2C,
        issuer: config.creds.issuer,
        passReqToCallback: config.creds.passReqToCallback,
        scope: config.creds.scope,
        loggingLevel: config.creds.loggingLevel,    
        nonceLifetime: config.creds.nonceLifetime,
        nonceMaxAmount: config.creds.nonceMaxAmount,
        useCookieInsteadOfSession: config.creds.useCookieInsteadOfSession,
        cookieEncryptionKeys: config.creds.cookieEncryptionKeys,
        clockSkew: config.creds.clockSkew,
      },
        function (iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, done) { 

            const request = require('request');

            const options = {
                url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=displayName,extension_db,extension_server',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': "Bearer " + accessToken,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            };

            function callback(error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
                    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
                    console.log('body:', body); 
                    var data = JSON.parse(response.body);
                    server = data.extension_server;
                    db = data.extension_db;
                } else {
                    console.log(response.statusCode);
                }
            }
            request(options, callback);

        if (!profile.oid) {
          return done(new Error("No oid found"), null);
        }
        // asynchronous verification, for effect...
        process.nextTick(function () {
          findByOid(profile.oid, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
              return done(err);
              }
            if (!user) {
              // "Auto-registration"
                users.push(profile);
              return done(null, profile);
              }

            return done(null, user);
          });
        });
      }
    ));


//config database
var sql = require("mssql");

var config = {
    user: '****',
    password: '*****',
    server: server,
    database: db
};
```

I want to configure the database based on the fields that I receive from the get request. The issue that I'm having is passport.use happens after the config is already set and all of my other code, including the routes are executed. How can I make it so that passport.use happens first after logging in?

Comment: I think you need to configure a session state in order to do this.